# New domain redirected to wrong website

Tags: dns, registration, domainservices, nameservers

I registered a new domain with [domain4me.in](http://domain4me.in). But when i visit, it redirected to wrong website. I have assigned the name servers (50webs.com), which is not related to this wrong website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some checks on www.whatsmydns.net. When you first purchase a domain and make the nameserver changes it can take up to 48 hours for the changes to propagate.

The above service will help you pinpoint what the nameservers are set as as well as if your records are set correctly.